# Entity framework 6 connecting multiple database implemention advice

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am a novice when it comes to entity framework.I usually use ado.net because is faster than any ORM and the repetitive code can be easily generated.

Now I have decided to give EF6 a go again and gain some experience in EF

Scenario.

Need to migrate data for many clients.(30 databases)

1. Each client will have their own staging database
2. Each database will have different tables
3. All databases will have/share the same "Views" schema.

Basically we decided that regardless of the clients tables ,they must all share the same Views.
So when we read the data we dont care because the views columnNames will be the same for them all.

**Ado.net Implementation**

Is very simple.I my dal i have methods like "GetCustomers","GetAccounts" etc... and all I need to do is change the connectionString 
and I can read the views from any database.Does not get simpler than this.

**EF implementation**

Please correct me if I am wrong.
In order for EF to work I would have to generate code for 30 databases (databaseFirst).

Is there a way I can use just a connection string to connect to the right database and based on that connection string read data from the views?

How would you do it using EF6 by just changing the connection string?

Can you give a noddy example how to do it?

Any suggestions

Comment: I correct you, you are, at least partially, wrong. You can use Code First on an existing database: mapping your classes to views. Code once, change connection string as wished.

Comment: @tschmit007 thanks,that is very encouraging any links or example or could you spare 10 mins with a noddy sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is, just a bit more of 10 minutes... (EF 5 on .net 4.5)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testef {               
    public class EntityZ {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String P1 { get; set; }
    }        

    public class EntityZConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityZ> {
        public EntityZConfiguration()
            : base() {
            ToTable("v", "dbo"); // the view
            HasKey(x => x.Id); //required

            //the mapping of properties
            Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            Property(x => x.P1).HasColumnName("value");
        }
    }  

    public class TestEFContext : DbContext {            
        public DbSet<EntityZ> Entities { get; set; }

        public TestEFContext(String cs)
            : base(cs) {
            //Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFContext>());
            Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(null);

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityZConfiguration());
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //creating the db 
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True")) {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                    com.CommandText = "declare @v int = 0 select @v = 1 from sys.databases where name = 'TestEF' if @v = 1 drop database TestEF";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    com.CommandText = "create database TestEF";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    com.CommandText = "use TestEF";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    com.CommandText = "create table t (i int not null, t nvarchar(max))";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    com.CommandText = "insert into  t (i, t) values (1, 'hello world')";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    com.CommandText = "create view v as select i as id, t as value from t";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            String cs = @"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            using (TestEFContext ctx = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
                foreach (EntityZ z in ctx.Entities) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", z.Id, z.P1);
                }

            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ,THANKS for your time.Appreciated!!!.I will put together a proof of concept and see if it works. looking at your code.I could have a set of sql scripts that creates the database for each client and then use your code excluding the creation of the db to connect to the database and then the rest should work for everyone.Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks that works,I will have to generate an id in the views,I just have to read about codefirst a bit.Any links to a good example with a a basic infrastructure. Eg to use or not to use repository pattern.also OnModelCreating I suppose you add many configuration eg CustomerConfiguration-EmployeeConfiguration etc... I am trying to get some sort good structure .any ideas links that you have seen used